# What does the Rustling grass mean?

Tags: pokemon-go

The rustling grass is driving me crazy - does it actually mean something? I've tried walking towards it, I mean I have actually walked in circles for five minutes in a Home Depot parking lot and in my neighborhood, but nothing ever comes of it.  I've tried tapping the screen where the grass is rustling - nothing.  Sometimes I see little pieces of green, other times it is substantially bigger. But never a pay off.  What am I missing?

Comment: well, I don't think it is the exact same question ;)  But by your tagging it as such I can only conclude that not only 'a Pokemon may or may not reside here [rustling grass]' but that it also has no other significant meaning and I should just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

> **Grass Shaking**: A Pokemon may or may not reside there. Higher chances of encountering a wild Pokemon. -- [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4rvuj2/how_do_i_megathread_part_4/)

When you are tracking a Pokemon by how close they are, you might want to try to go to the grass spots first. You may be lucky and the pokemon is there. If it is not there you just continue looking for it, but it was still worth trying since the spots have higher probability of having a pokemon nearby.

Comment: I walked to ~20 grass spots. All empty.

Comment: Bad luck I guess... Or not. I've walked into a few empty ones myself (something like half of them were empty). This could also be a placebo or some way to give players some initial direction to go (like I described in my answer)

Comment: when I see rustling grass all 'nearby' are at least three footsteps away and I am basically standing on the rustling grass.